# How to get Product Target Path programmatically in product edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm trying to get the latest Target Path to show up in the backend of Magento on the product edit page.

I've tried everything I can think of to try to get it but I usually get NULL.

I've managed to do this to get the URL key...

```
$productId = $this->getProductId();
$path = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore());
echo $path;
```

Which gives 'sample-url-key', however, I'm trying to get the latest Target Path - the actual path on the frontend since 2 products have this URL and this product's target path is actually 'sample-url-key-14'.

I can't seem to get it to load by using

```
 $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath($path)
```

or

```
$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByIdPath($path)
```

These both return NULL.

I've also tried another method I read about

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)
->addUrlRewrite();
$path = $product_collection->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl();
echo $path;
```

This $path returns https://example.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/14/

I'm trying to find a way to show what the *actual* URL will be when viewing this product on the frontend, not what is just in the URL key field since that's not accurate for duplicate/rewritten URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/url')->generatePath('target', $_product);?>
```